# Angular Materials autocomplete data loading but not filtering working perfectly angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

This is my HTML code. form the example I took the code. [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/redxejmejyn?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts). But filtering when typing is not working

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input type="text" formControlName="planClient" matInput placeholder="Plan Client" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let client of filteredOptions | async" [value]="client">
      {{client}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is my .ts file

```js
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
clients: string[] = [
  'Alabama',
  'California',
  'Colorado',
  'Connecticut',
  'SelectHealth',
  'UMR'
];
planClient = new FormControl();

this.filteredOptions = this.planClient.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(value => this._filter(value))
  );

public _filter(value: string): string[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  return this.clients.filter(client => client.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change formControlName to [formControl]
`<input type="text" [formControl]="planClient" matInput placeholder="Plan Client" [matAutocomplete]="auto">`

Comment: Is it the same [formControl]="planClient" and formControlName="planClient"? @Ininiv

Comment: Not exactly, FormControlName - Syncs FormControl in an existing FormGroup instance to a form control element by name. Refer https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to change the `formControlName` to property binding using follwing way.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

**Here is [Demo on Stackblitz of your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fxmjt-j9n5wx?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html)**